# JPA EntityManager doesn't commit changes in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have an SQLite database. I work with it using EclipseLink and JPA. In addition I have an entity class `User`:

```
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    long id;            // Unique identifier of the user in the DB
    String username;    // Unique name used for login
    String password;    // Password used for login

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

In a registration form I create a user and then call an `EntityManager` to `persist()` the changes:

```
public int createUser(String username, String password, String password_confirmation) {
        int regStatus = 0;
        if(checkValidUsername(username)) {
            if(checkValidPassword(password, password_confirmation)) {
                EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
                try {
                    em.getTransaction().begin();
                        User user = new User(username, password);
                        em.persist(user);
                    em.getTransaction().commit();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    regStatus = 3;
                }
                finally {
                    em.close();
                }
            }
            else regStatus = 2; // Password mismatch
        }
        else regStatus = 1;     // User with selected username already present in DB

        return regStatus;
    }
```

It works without any problems. I get each and every newly registered user in my `USER` table. However when I try to change the password it doesn't work. Here are the methods that are related to this procedure:

```
// Inside the controller for my settings view - here the user can change various things related to his/her profile
public void setCurrentUser() {
    currentUser = UserController.findUserByName((String)VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("username")); // findUserByName() is a static method
}


// Inside the User controller I have multiple methods for common user-related queries; here I use the username that I have retrieved from the VaadinSession's attribute "username" to execute a query and get the User entity (I make sure that a user's name is unique so getting a single result here is not a problem)
public static User findUserByName(String username) {
    if(username == null) return null;
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    User user = null;

    try{
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username");
        q.setParameter("username", username);
        user = (User)q.getSingleResult();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return user;
}


// Inside the controller fpr my settings view (where I change the password)
public int changePassword(String currentPassword, String newPassword, String newPasswordConfirmation) {
    if(newPassword.isEmpty()) return 1;
    if(!newPassword.equals(newPasswordConfirmation)) return 2;          // Incorrect confirmation
    if(!currentPassword.equals(currentUser.getPassword())) return 3;    // Given current password doesn't match the one stored in the database for this user

    int resStatus = 0;
    EntityManager em  = factory.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
            currentUser.setPassword(newPassword);
        em.getTransaction().commit(); // NO ERRORS at all...
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        resStatus = 4;  // Exception
    }
    finally {
      em.close();
    }

    return resStatus;
}
```

I have also tried using `EntityManager.find(...)`, which should return the same row from the `USER` table (and it does) but the result is again the same - transaction begins, finishes, entity manager closes but the table `USER` for the supposedly changed user is the same.

Any ideas? I have used the same routine in another project but for setting other things. The database there was PostreSQL and I haven't encountered such issues. Here with the SQLite database I get no errors but the commit fails somehow.

Comment: does Eclipselink provide full support for SQLite? I know it didn't used to, and I've used DataNucleus whenever I've wanted to use that datastore. Looking at the EclipseLink log would likely reveal plenty

Comment: I don't see any commit of the transaction when I trigger the change of password. Also where can I find some information on what EclipseLink supports when it comes to SQLite. I tried looking here and there but nothing came up. Still I really doubt that it would support `persist()` (using a transaction!) but not a simple change of a value in a column. I think that the error is somewhere else in the code I gave. Just don't know where. Debugging doesn't help at all since I get no error whatsoever.

Comment: Well if I search "Eclipselink supported databases" I get http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#What_databases_are_supported.3F

Comment: and look at what state "currentUser" is when you want to update its field. Is it managed? detached?

Comment: It will be detached because he obtains a new EntityManager using factory.createEntityManager() for the transaction.  The user needs to be merged or read in using that EntityManager

Answer (score 1):

I just develop with hibernate etc. but it will be the same, because both implements JPA. 
If you start a transaction JPA will remember all entities you load in this transaction and if you change something you will see the changes in db (after commit).

But in your transaction JPA don't recognize your entity and so the changes will not persists. Try to load the entity in the transaction. Like...

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.find(User.class, currentUser.getId()); //Reload the User from db, so it is attached to the session
        currentUser.setPassword(newPassword);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

More Information about the methods:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)
- http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed

Comment: Refresh will throw an exception since the instance isn't managed.  It needs to be merged or read in.

Comment: It would be strange if you try to change the password of an user doesn't exist in database :P But you are right, refresh would be a problem, if the object is not in database.    There could be also a problem, if you refresh an object after creating it. So there would be no row in db. In that case you have to use a flush.     For this case refresh or merge would be ok. Or you could save the object after modifying it, would be a third way to do the same.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean refresh is a problem if the row isn't there, I meant it is a problem if the instance you pass in isn't managed in the current context.  Refresh is only valid on instances managed by this EntityManager, so the entity read in from any other em and passed around would cause an exception.  Since they are closing the context after reading in the currentUser, and obtaining a different one for the update, I was suggesting your solution needs to be updated to use find operation instead of refresh, or use merge.